# grep for full raw multi-line string

Tags: grep

This the following

```bash
$ echo '
  - key: val
    baz: foo
' | grep -F "$(
cat <<EOM
  - key: val
    foo: baz
EOM
)"
```

The output is a partial match

```
  - key: val
```

but I would like to get nothing if the whole given heredoc string is fully found and nothing otherwise.

Is it possible to grep for full raw multi-line string (not a regular expression)? If so, then how should it be done?

Comment: @anubhava It does not give an exact match. For instance, adding more spaces at the beginning of the input still returns a match and still still the partial match happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing is that to get exact match in `grep` you will need to use `-x` option.

However, as I suspected initially `grep -x` will fail for even the full match due to presence of line breaks.

One trick is to use `tr` to strip all line breaks from original and pattern strings and use `-x` like this:

```bash
echo '
  - key: val
    baz: foo
' | tr -d '\n' | grep -q -xF -- "$(
cat <<EOM | tr -d '\n'
  - key: val
    foo: baz
EOM
)" && echo "match" || echo "nope"


echo '
  - key: val
    baz: foo
' | tr -d '\n' | grep -q -xF -- "$(
cat <<EOM | tr -d '\n'
  - key: val
    baz: foo
EOM
)" && echo "match" || echo "nope"
```

**Output:**

```bash
nope
match
```

Note use of `-q` to suppress normal output of `grep` and use only the exit code. Also used `--` to separate options from pattern.